# Why addresses from the exchanges do not show on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, exchanges

I have some ether in an exchange but when I searched it on etherscan.io it is showing

> There are no matching entries

there I got to know exchanges have the balances on their own wallet address, but if my address(from exchange account) is not there on blockchain how I am able to send ether from outside my exchange account to the address?

Answer (score 1):

By "exchange" I assume you mean a centralized exchange.

Exchanges do have real wallets. Whenever you deposit any asset to an exchange you send it to one of their (hot) wallets and after that the exchange's inner logic perhaps sends it somewhere further.

When trading inside an exchange it's all done inside the exchange's internal ledgers to minimize costs and delays. When you transfer assets out again the exchange sends them from a real wallet.

Comment: So if deposited ether to my own address(address got from the exchange) from outside so it will not be deposited to my address, it will deposit to exchange address.
If that is true then how it directly deposited to the exchange address while I made a payment to my own address, Or first it will come to my address, and then they will move it to their address.

Comment: Well that is all internal exchange business logic so it's hard to say for sure. Probably they generate you a one-time-use address where you send the assets (so that they know those are your assets) and then they forward the assets to a common exchange hot wallet.

Comment: I think they transfer from our address when we deposit from the outside because they have keys for the generated address(by exchanges).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.

The addresses from an exchange are handled in various different ways based on the internal decision of the exchange.

With some you'll find that the wallet address shown on your account on the exchange is similar to any other wallet address, and its transactions are viewable on etherscan.

With others, you might find that the address is a proxy for the exchange to maintain some sort of internal check's and balances (to avoid user sending incorrect tokens to the incorrect address)...

And multiple other ways that exchanges can and do handle deposits and withdrawals.